# How to reuse maven's .repository contents to avoid redownloading external dependencies on each project's build?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have multiple Jenkins Java projects with external dependencies. I'd like Jenkins to avoid redownloading each Maven project's external dependencies (the contents of .repository) on every build. Currently each project uses a private repo and wipes away it's workspace on each build.

Here are the solutions I was thinking of. However, I am not that familiar with Jenkins and Java, so I am on a bit of a learning curve.

- Do not use a private maven repository per project. Use the default `/home/jenkins/.m2/.repository` directory for each project. The external dependencies could be used on each subsequent build.
- Find some tool to cache the external (is this what artifactory or nexus are used for?) dependencies, so it's not as expensive to download them on each build.
- Don't wipe away the entire project workspace at the beginning of each build. Selectively remove files and keep the workspaces .repository directory, so the directory can be leveraged on each build.

How can I avoid redownloading the dependencies each time? Is there a standard way to handle the above situation? Ultimately, I'd like to reduce the build times. Downloading the packages takes a long time, causing the builds to sometimes takes 45 minutes or longer.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: "is this what artifactory or nexus are used for?" They can be used for this, among other things.

Comment: The first question: 45 minutes for what exactly? The full build including test/downloading etc. some more information needed: How many modules, how many classes and how many tests are you running? Apart from that 45 minutes sounds really strange... ? Do you use fast machine (with SSD storage; enough RAM/CPU's ?) ? And analyse what exactly takes time? Downloading? Really using an internal network? If not install a repository manager in your network etc. ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The downloading of dependancies takes around 40 minutes of a build that takes 45 minutes in total. We are behind a corporate proxy. Neither RAM nor CPU is the bottleneck. I think the initial intention of my question was to find a way to prevent redownloading dependancies from Maven central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right.

- 100% agree, it's better to use common local repository. All artifacts have versions and it's safe to reuse them among different projects.
- Yes, Nexus and Artifactory are used exactly for this purpose. Usually, such local tool in your local network is much faster. Also, they usually store build artifacts (`.jar` or `.war` files) which you can use as dependencies in other projects.
- This point makes sense, but I did not see it in practice. If you can set it up, then build time should be reduces even more. But if something goes wrong with this cache (eg corrupted artifact is cached) then you have to resolve it (probably manually).

Also I would recommend to analyze build time deeply. How much time do you actually spend on the dependency downloading? I don't believe that it takes majority of the time build.